# Open Last File save base on creation date, NOT Last modify

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new on VBA, currently, I been seen the way to open a workbook base on creation date, I have found several codes but this open last save workbook or last modify file, sometimes last files are not the workbook I need and I will like to replace from last save file to the creation date.

Below its an example of code, I have found.

```
Sub NewestFile()

    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim LatestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date

    MyPath = "C:\Users\Documents\"
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)

    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

        If LMD > LatestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            LatestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

End Sub
```

Comment: This requires accessing the Windows API via VBA. If still available, see the late Chip Pearson's article on [Changing File Times with VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/FileTimes.htm)

Comment: FileSystemObject has a method for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datecreated-property (assuming you're not on a Mac)